# copiar el valor de una variable no funciona en nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Mi función es:

```
var copia;
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) { 
    copia=rows[0].max_id;
    console.log(rows[0].max_id); 
});
console.log(copia);
```

la variable `copia` muestra el valor `undefined`, no copia el número de `rows[0].max_id`; cuando imprimo `console.log(rows[0].max_id);`, muestra un número diferente.

**NOTA:** `copia` es una variable global.

Comment: La variable `copia` debería mostrar `undefined`, no `0` ya que la estás declarando encima y no le estas poniendo valor

Comment: @devconcept cierto sale undefined!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así es como está ejecutando realmente tu programa

```
var copia;
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ');
console.log(copia); // Aquí aun no tiene valor
// Unos segundos después cuando la consulta termina 
copia=rows[0].max_id; // Aquí es donde le asignas el valor
console.log(rows[0].max_id);
```

Estás intentando imprimir su valor antes de que la consulta termine por esa razón no tendrá el valor que esperas.

Tienes que mover toda la lógica que dependa de dicha variable `copia` para este bloque

```
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) { 
    copia=rows[0].max_id;
    // Luego que tiene valor trabajas con ella
    // El resto del código va aquí
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No estás entendiendo la naturaleza del lenguaje JavaScript. JavaScript es un lenguaje **asíncrono**, es decir, un bloque de código, no está alineado siempre a la línea temporal del siguiente bloque.

En JavaScript hay algo que se llama `callback`. Un callback es una función que que se le puede pasar a otra sin alterar la línea de tiempo de la función principal. Esta es la naturaleza de la programación asíncrono, poder tener varios procesos en paralelo.

**¿Qué es lo que pasa?**

Lo que pasa es que tanto `console.log(copia)` como el callback `function(err, rows, fields) { ... }` se **ejecutan en diferentes líneas de tiempo**, por lo tanto, es normal que `copia` aún no tenga el valor asignado en el callback.

**¿Qué puedo hacer?**

Para hacer el código más modular, puedes pasarle `rows[0].max_id` a una función.

```
objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario ', function(err, rows, fields) { 
    afterQuery(rows[0].max_id); 
});

// seguir con el flujo
function afterQuery(maxId) {
  copia = maxId;
}
```

**ES6/8**

Si quieres un estilo más "procedural", puedes apoyarte es las últimas versiones de EcmaScript (6,7,8) mediante polyfills.

- [node-mysql-promises](https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql).
- [async/await](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait)

Con estos módulos, tu código se vería así:

```
// flujo natural
let rows = await getMaxId();
copia = rows[0].max_id;

function async getMaxId() {
  return objBD.query('select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario');
}
```

Comment: vengo de lenguajes procedurales, algún libro para aprender programación asincrona?

Comment: Hay varios libros buenos de JavaScript, por ejemplo: JavaScript: the good parts (viejo pero muy bueno para entender el lenguaje), Secrets of the JavaScript ninja (del creador de jQuery - 2016) y Eloquent JavaScript. Si puedes en físico mejor ;)

Comment: `poder tener varios procesos en paralelo` no es realmente asi, pues javascript es single thread, por lo que no ocuren las cosas en paralelo (salvo por los webworkers) sino que se basa en eventos que se procesan en serie. osea uno detras de otro.

Comment: @rnd No me refería a **threads**, si no a **sucesos**. Typo error ;)

Comment: como seria la solucion con promises?